Close other dropdown on click of another dropdown
I am using angular in my application. I have a custom dropdown component. I am using the same custom dropdown component for 3 purpose in a single page. When one dropdown is open and i am trying to open another dropdown then the already opened dropdown is not closing.
Please suggest how can we resolve this.
customdropdown:
<div>
 <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index">
     <button (click)="selectItem($event, item, i)"></button>
  </li>
 <ul>
</div>

employee.page.ts

   <custom-dropdown
          [options]="empCode"
          (onSelect)="onSelectEmpCode($event)">
   </custom-dropdown>

     <custom-dropdown
          [options]="empName"
          (onSelect)="onSelectEmpName($event)">
   </custom-dropdown>

   <custom-dropdown
          [options]="empSalary"
          (onSelect)="onSelectEmpSalary($event)">
   </custom-dropdown>


please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated reference stackblitz
